# How can I use java 8 streams to get values from my hashmap

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a hashmap that looks something like this:

```
Map<String, ImageRecipeMap> contentIdToImageIdsMap = new HashMap<>();
```

my ImageRecipeMap object looks something like this:

```
public class ImageRecipeMap {

    private ContentType contentType;

    private List<String> imageIds;

    public List<String> getImageIds() {
        return imageIds;
    }

    public void setImageIds(List<String> imageIds) {
        this.imageIds = imageIds;
    }

    ...
}
```

I want to grab all the Lists of imageIds and create a total imageIds list using java 8 streams. This is what I have so far, but I seem to have a compile error on my collect:

```
List<String> total = contentIdToImageIdsMap.values().stream()
           .map(value -> value.getImageIds())
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: the compile error I'm getting is that collect in stream cannot be applied

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution returns `List<List<String>>`.  Use `.flatMap()` to flatten them like this.

```
    List<String> total = contentIdToImageIdsMap.values().stream()
           .flatMap(value -> value.getImageIds().stream())
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`.flatMap()` changes `Stream<List<String>>` to `Stream<String>`.

Comment: yes, that looks like it did the trick. Can you explain what the difference between flatMap and map is? And why would my ids be converted into another stream? Thanks

Comment: getImageIds().stream() will create a Stream<String> object for each element in your map. With map, you would have a Stream<Stream<String>> or a _stream composed of stream of strings_. flatMap will _glue_ all the streams of strings together into a single stream and give you a simple Stream<String>